# How do compilers allocate memory for classes?

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

When I make a class with a class pointer like:

```
class A{
    B* p_b1;
    B* p_b2;
    A(){}
}
```

I assume the compiler generates space for at least the size of 2 pointers per A instance. My question is, if they were not pointers but rather straight up objects like:

```
class A{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    A(){}
}
```

Will the compiler allocate space for b1 and b2 within the memory space of the A class? Or will it declare the actual B classes elsewhere on the stack?

The reason I ask this is because I am trying to reduce memory allocations within my code and was wandering if it would make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: what do u mean else where on the stack? in your examples b1, b2 are created on stack. if you want to reduce memory allocations, then use less objects (including one's created on heap)

Comment: also compiler never allocates space. run time does!

Comment: @Nandu Yes but the machine needs to allocate memory on the stack for every object. Thus I had to ask if it was gonna generalize the allocation to cover for ALL objects within. Essentially "sharing" the stack allocation.

Comment: The x86 machine won't need to allocate memory on the stack for every object. Static allocation and using heaps are alternative. What is your architecture?

Comment: The memory has to be allocated somewhere, so you can't reduce allocations without reducing the amount of stuff you need in memory. Perhaps you mean *dynamic* memory allocation? Or maybe you're talking about the number of memory pages allocated by the kernel?

Comment: @tweej No I'm well aware of how to use dynamic memory allocation. This is specifically for stack allocation.

Comment: In that case, for your second case, it doesn't really matter where the objects are on the stack. If the pages backing your stack are large enough to support the size of A and its members, allocation of more memory pages will not be required. If the area mapping the stack isn't large enough, then you'll get a page fault, followed by more memory pages allocated by the kernel up until the stack limit. For your first case, it depends on if A's constructor allocates new B objects, or just copies pointers to already-existing B objects. These are OS memory-management implementation details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the compiler allocate space for b1 and b2 within the memory space of the A class?

Yes.

> Or will it declare the actual B classes elsewhere on the stack?

No.

> The reason I ask this is because I am trying to reduce memory allocations within my code and was wandering if it would make any difference whatsoever.

Yes, it would make a difference. Allocating memory on the stack is way more efficient than allocating memory from the heap. If you can, prefer the stack to heap for memory allocation when performance becomes an issue.

Comment: doesn't that depend on the problem? ex: vector of objects Vs vector of pointers - stack Vs heap

Comment: The second example is more efficient even if the object of class A is created on the heap, as it will result in one heap allocation instead of three.

Comment: @Nandu, When you have a vector of objects, there is not much on the stack. Most of the memory is on the heap. If you have a vector of pointers, you have two levels of heap memory, one for the memory allocated for the "data" of the vector and one for the objects themselves.

Comment: true. But you mention when performance becomes an issue, prefer stack to heap. How does that fit into context of vectors (or STL container's) that grow?? doesn't having objects on heap offer better performance in these cases??

Comment: @Nandu, when using a vector, you don't have a choice about where the "data" is allocated, it is always on the heap. That does not give you better performance than an array created using stack memory. It gives you other benefits -- dynamic sizing, ability to create much larger arrays, come to mind. But it won't be better performing than creating an array on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends.  Anything which is a field of an object will get allocated the same way as the object (both on the stack or both on the heap).  If you are looking to reduce allocations, you may look into reusing objects.  You can call a destructor by hand and then call the [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) expression to reuse the object's memory.

If, on the other hand, you are looking to simply reduce the size of the stack used, then allocate on the heap in constructor and deallocate in destructor ([RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)).